# Why is Power Query looking for a comma here?

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery, m

So I have this bit of code:

```html
let 
   Yearpop=0,
   Yeardeath=0

if #"Added index" [#"country-year"] {[Index]} =
   #"Added index" [#"country-year"] {[Index]+1}

then Yeardeath=Yeardeath+[Number of deaths], 
 Yearpop=Yearpop+[Total population]

else (Yeardeath*100000)/Yearpop,
 Yeardeath=0,
 Yearpop=0
```

The *if* is underlined in red, and my error message says "Token Comma Expected." Since if statements wouldn't need a comma, and I only defined two variables, I don't get why that error is showing up?

The point of the code is to clean up a data set: I have columns where the # of suicides are sorted by age range and sex, and I want to add up all the deaths and populations to get a total suicide rate for the country that year.

Comment: It’s not at all clear what you are trying to do, if you add some screenshots and/or dummy data showing what you have and what you want it will make it easier.

Comment: There are multiple problems at work here. You should probably step back and explain what you're trying to do first because M doesn't quite work the way you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: Because you got the syntax wrong.

Look at the following example which also has a wrong syntax and will not work

```
let    
   Yearpop=0,    
   Yeardeath=0,    
   if Yeardeath = 1 then result = 1 else result = 0
 in 
    result
```

You have to use the syntax for [let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/expressions-values-and-let-expression)

```
let    
   Yearpop=0,    
   Yeardeath=0,    
   result = if Yeardeath = 1 then 1 else 0  
 in 
    result
```

Further reading on [let](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/05/22/understanding-let-expressions-in-m-for-power-bi-and-power-query/)